# Как передать значение атрибута кнопки в SQL-запрос?

Tags: javascript, sql, json, ajax

Есть кнопки с атрибутами data-id

```
<button id="updatedetail" data-id="1">Редактировать</button>
<button id="updatedetail" data-id="2">Редактировать</button>
<button id="updatedetail" data-id="3">Редактировать</button>
```

Далее следует вывод данных из БД на php

```
<div id="detailname">

<?php 
$detail_object = mysqli_query ($connection, "SELECT * FROM `detail` WHERE `id`='...'");
$detail = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($detail_object);
?> 

<p><?php echo $detail['name']; ?></p>

</div>
```

Как при нажатии кнопки передать значение атрибута в SQL запрос, а конкретно в часть WHERE `id`='...' ?

P.S. Пробовал ajax, но почему-то на моем примере не работает

```
document.querySelectorAll('#updatedetail').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var showid = e.dataset.id;
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'modal.php'; 
    const data = {id: showid}

    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
    request.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            modal.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        } else {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    request.send(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Что именно с ajax запросом у вас не получается?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , не понимаю, как использовать ajax в сочетании с SQL

Comment: Ты уже написал ajax и столкнулся с проблемой или в целом не знаешь про ajax ничего, кроме что он существует?)) Если первое - добавь в вопрос, напиши что не получается

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , дополнил описание вопроса

Comment: А что подставляешь в итоге в `\`id\`='...'"`? данные приходят вообще?................. + вместо устаревшего ещё 10 лет назад  XHR  посмотри в сторону fetch, проще использовать и легче отследить все манипуляции.... ....в целом тебе нужно воспользоваться отладкой как на фронте так и на бэке. чтобы посмотреть где что у тебя происходит

Comment: В `id`='...'" мне нужно подставить data-id из ссылки, на которую кликнули

Comment: это понятно.......ну ты вот отправляешь...на сервере получается должен прилететь `$_POST['id']`..... ты его подставляешь? или ты не знаешь что подставлять?

Comment: Я подставил WHERE `id`='" . $_POST['id'] . "', но ничего не передается

Comment: А ты посмотрел, вообще есть такое значение на бэке? Во-вторых, как ты вычислил, что не передаётся? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482  - почитай про то, как велючить отображение ошибок и как отлаживать свой код

Answer (score 0):

если ловишь значени id через POST, то

```
$id = $_POST['updatedetail'];
```

если через GET то,

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
```

ну а в SQL просто передаешь $id

```
"SELECT * FROM `detail` WHERE `id`='{$id}'"
```

Comment: а в коде ajax что-то нужно поменять? почему-то не работает